# What is the laws of cause and effect in Mirai Nikki?

Tags: mirai-nikki

I was reading over Deus on the Mirai Nikki wiki. I was reading the following sentence [here](http://futurediary.wikia.com/wiki/Deus_Ex_Machina) but I do not understand what it is meant by "cause and effect". Heres an extract of that sentence:

> Deus Ex Machina is the God of Time and Space and a major character of Future Diary manga and anime...... Able to manipulate time, space, and the laws of **cause and effect**, Deus is the most powerful character in the series and acts as the judge of the survival game.

However I do not understand what the *laws* of cause and effect are? What does this mean? Does it mean that he can influence others destinys or lives? Change the outcome?

What are the laws of cause and effect? I cannot remember them being mentioned before. So to summarise I am asking....

1. What ***is*** the laws of cause and effect. E.g. they are....
2. What ***are*** they. E.g. One cannot do this.... you can do that....

Does anyone know?

Comment: I think this doesn't mean anything, just some words a wikia editor thought would be cool to throw in for effect.

Comment: "he can influence others destinies or lives" Deus never intervene the game, but he give some power to Minene because muru muru try to manipulate the game. With that, he can do anything and change the outcome of the game if he want.

Comment: but I doubt if 'laws of cause and effect' here meaning he can change someone destiny. It's more about the diary, if someone do something different after seeing his diary, it will change what happen next. Like when Yuki decided to open the door, Deus fully understand what is that means and it change the game of survival entirely and change every other diary. It's something like [the Butterfly effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_effect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's just refer to the general **Causality** concept.

From [Causality's Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality)

> Causality (also referred to as causation) is the relation between an event (the cause) and a second event (the effect), where the second event is understood as a consequence of the first.

There's also **Causation** [Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causation_%28disambiguation%29)

From [God and the Laws of Science: The Law of Causality](http://www.apologeticspress.org/apcontent.aspx?category=12&article=3716)

> - “the principle that nothing can happen without being caused” (“Causality,” 2009).
> - “the principle that everything has a cause” (“Causality,” 2008).

and [The Principle of Causality](https://www.marxists.org/reference/archive/spirkin/works/dialectical-materialism/ch02-s06.html#AEN418)

> Nowhere in the world can there be any phenomena that do not give rise to certain consequences and have not been caused by other phenomena.

And according to the link you gave, even the room where Deus located is called **Cathedral of Causality**

Hope those above answer the first question.

For the second question, I guess you refer to the content of the law? As far as I know and understand, it's simply the same as its definition:

> “...nothing can happen without being caused” (“Causality,” 2009).

Hope this helps, and sorry if I'm out of topic or get your question wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, he made this statement to describe his creation of the future diaries. That said, whatever the original laws of cause and effect were, and whatever his alterations to the were, we know that the result is that people are now able to know events that will take place in the future.

So at the very least, it can be concluded that the law of cause and effect that was changed is the law that it is impossible for a person to know future events, but the changing of this law has several loose ends that must be addressed as well:

1. Is the diary holder's mere knowledge of the event enough to alter the future? In the anime, the answer is no. A player must take action contrary or antithetical to the predicted event.
2. Is a diary holder's propensity or volition to take actions contrary to a prediction enough to change it? This isn't made entirely clear in the anime, as sometimes a character's volition to take different actions changes the prediction, while other times it doesn't.

So the two above items most likely constitute the "changes to the laws of time and space" that Deus made.